# python numbers in different sequence in file

Tags: python, bash

I am new to python and bash.

I don't know what to really search up, so forgive me if this is a duplicate.

I have a python file like this:

```
  if(word[3] == 'l' and 
    word[4] == 'e' and 
    word[1] == 'f' and 
    word[2] == 'i' and ):
```

And I would like to get the array in order. This of course can be done manually by mapping 1 to f, 2 to i, so on and so forth, but I would like to know how to do this with a bigger array, either in python or bash, it doesn't matter that much.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean like you have array and till it ends what should happen

Comment: Did you mean: `if word[1:5] = 'file':`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "if(" is not in the file, you can use sort in bash.

```
sort filename
```